# How much does one night of reduced sleep impair immune function?

Tags: immune-system, sleep, research, statistics

I just watched the [Sleep is your superpower](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MuIMqhT8DM&t=587s) TED talk by Prof. Matt Walker.  In that video, he claims that 1 night of sleeping only 4 hours reduces natural killer cell activity by 70%.

My first question is: Is this true? I couldn't find a study that shows an NK cell activity drop this drastic. I was able to find [an article by Peter Attita, MD](https://peterattiamd.com/fighting-cancer-improving-immune-function-with-sleep/) that includes a talk with Matt Walker and a link to a [UCLA study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7871104/) that shows "NK cell activity was reduced ... to a level 72% of the mean of three separate baseline values."  Which is a 28% drop.

I have found this statement of a 70% drop all over the internet (possibly because of Matt Walker's talk), but I have not been able to find a source. What paper is Matt Walker citing?

Secondly, how does a 70% drop in NK activity correlate to a drop in immune system capability? The TED talk leads people to believe that there is a 70% drop in immune system function, but that is not actually what is being stated. What is the overall drop in immune function if you sleep only 4 hours?

Thirdly, the blue elements look like antibodies; that doesn't look like an image of natural killer cells at all. Am I misunderstanding something, or is the image just a pretty picture for people with no medical knowledge?

Comment: The immune system is incredibly complex, involving dozens of specialized cell types and fighting off hundreds or even thousands of types of pathogens all the time. No researcher could possibly rigorously analyze the effect of 4 hours of sleep deprivation on such a complex process. TED talks are for tickling the imagination, not meaningful scientific evidence.

Comment: I don't want to discourage asking questions like this, because I think it's all good critical thinking, but it really shows the weakness of the TED talk format and other similar venues - there's little link between claims made and the actual underlying science. You probably need to ask Matt Walker who he is citing, anyone else could at best try to guess, as you've already done in guessing that he's confusing a "drop to 70%" as a "70% drop".

Comment: Well, Matt Walker's science might be a tad too overhyped: [Criticism link 1](https://markusloecher.github.io/TroubleWithTED/), [Criticism link 2](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2019/11/18/is-matthew-walkers-why-we-sleep-riddled-with-scientific-and-factual-errors/), [Criticism link 3](https://guzey.com/books/why-we-sleep/) (also referenced in criticism link 2).